# How to minimize occuring errors in Verlet Integration for orbital mechanics

Tags: python, numeric, orbit

it's my first time asking a question here and since i only started some days ago with coding i may need your help defining my problem a bit more precise.

I would like to simulate some keplerian orbits, but i have reoccurring problems with the required precision. For example when my point comes to close to the center of gravity it slings it out of every sensible orbit. (My theory is that the acceleration increases so drastically compared to the time-window dt, that it reaches escape velocity before gravity 'has a chance' to pull it back.) Another problem is that the orbit itself rotates around the center of gravity. I have not studied this problem in detail but i guess, this time small errors sum up thus creating this flower-like effect.

First thought why these errors occur:
As written in the title i use a simple Verlet integration to approximate the true solution. I know there are other possibilities like Runge-Kutta method, but i saw people doing some nice simulations with a simple Euler-Approximation. So i thought a second order Verlet-Approximation should be sufficient. Maybe this is not the case, so should i use another method of approximation?

Second idea:
I simply coded it badly and there are better ways to handle it, keeping numerical errors minimal. For further analysis i upload a snip of my small code here:

```
t = t + dt
i = 1
while t <= T and i <= n:
    #A_list was the idea of calculating the acceleration more efficient, i append the necessary entries, calculate the acceleration and delete the entries again to repeat the process  
    A_list.append(x_list[i])
    A_list.append(y_list[i])
    r    = np.sqrt(A_list[0]**2 + A_list[1]**2)
    A_x  = -(G*M/r**2) * A_list[0] * 1/r 
    A_y  = -(G*M/r**2) * A_list[1] * 1/r
    x_i1 = 2*A_list[0] - x_list[i-1] + A_x * dt**2
    y_i1 = 2*A_list[1] - y_list[i-1] + A_y * dt**2
    del A_list[1]
    del A_list[0]
    i = i + 1
    t = t + dt
    x_list.append(x_i1)
    y_list.append(y_i1)
    t_list.append(t)
```

I hope this was somewhat readable and there is someone who would like to help a young programmer out. :)

Pictures for clarification:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fh3v.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02em7.jpg)

Comment: I haven't looked closely at your code yet, but Verlet integration should be fine, assuming you've implemented it correctly. It's a symplectic integrator, so it conserves energy, unlike Euler or Runge-Kutta, which should be avoided in orbit sims. Another useful symplectic integrator is [Leapfrog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leapfrog_integration),  especially its synchronized form.

Comment: I used synchronized Leapfrog in [this Tkinter program](https://gist.github.com/PM2Ring/d7878c904df8da838f76dc4a15c6c746). Of course, with any orbit integrator you need to use a fairly small time step, especially with highly eccentric orbits, but you can get away with a larger timestep with a symplectic integrator, compared to what's needed for Euler or RK4.

Comment: It looks like you have coded Verlet correctly, assuming you've set the 1st two points correctly. BTW, that `A_list` stuff makes the code harder to read, and slower.

Comment: Thanks for your answer PM 2Ring :)
1.Then i gonna try Leapfrog as well in order to compare it to my Verlet Integration attempt.
2. I will take a look at your code. :)
3. Does a symplectic integrator conserve its form when i change the timesteps? (with reasonable spacing)
4. The first two points should be fine, so you would just recommend decreasing the time step itself for highly eccentric orbits=
5. gonna streamline that bit then. Thanks for the advise :)

Comment: Even with fairly large timesteps a symplectic integrator will conserve the Hamiltonian. It's just that the Hamiltonian will deviate more from the true energy of the system. With non-symplectics you need really small timesteps just to achieve orbits that close. Eg, using Euler to simulate the motion of Mars the time steps need to be smaller than 1 day. Using a symplectic integrator on a simple 2 body system (like in my code), the orbit will be a closed curve even with a fairly high timestep, but if the timestep's too high the orbit will precess, and that shouldn't happen in a 2 body system.

Comment: With a very eccentric orbit & a large timestep you get a huge acceleration if the body gets too close to the primary, and that can eject the body from the system. Of course, that could be the body's actual trajectory, depending on its initial position & velocity. :)